# If $ι:U→V$ is a Hilbert-Schmidt embedding and $(v_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, then $(ιι^*v_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ is an orthonormal basis of $ιU$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Let

- $(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U)$ and $(V,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V)$ be separable $\mathbb R$-Hilbert spaces
- $\iota:U\to V$ be a [Hilbert-Schmidt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator) embedding
- $T:=\iota\iota^\ast$
- $V_0:=T^{1/2}V$ be equipped with $$\langle u,v\rangle_{V_0}:=\langle T^{-1/2}u,T^{-1/2}v\rangle_V\;\;\;\text{for }u,v\in V_0\;,$$ where $$T^{-1}:=\left(\left.T\right|_{\ker(T)^\perp}\right)^{-1}$$ denotes the pseudo inverse of $T$

We can show that

1. $V_0=\iota U$ (in the sense of set equality)
2. $\iota$ is an isometry between $(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U)$ and $(V_0,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_{V_0})$
3. $T$ is a bounded, linear, nonnegative and symmetric operator on $V$ with finite [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class#Definition)

> Let $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a *suitable*$^1$ orthonormal basis of $(V,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V)$. Can we show that $(T^{1/2}v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal basis of $(V_0,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_{V_0})$?

If that's not possible, can we show it, if we assume that $U\subseteq V$ ($U$ and $V$ being still equipped with different inner products) and $\iota$ is the inclusion? Note that in that case $(V_0,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_{V_0})=(U,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_U)$.

---

$^1$ It's not important for me whether or not we can show the statement for every or only for a special choice of $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$. A necessary special choice might be the choice for which we've got $$Tv_n=\mu_nv_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N\tag 1$$ for some $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq[0,\infty)$. The existence of such a $(v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is guaranteed by the [Hilbert-Schmidt theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem).

Comment: ??? $\langle u,v \rangle_V =\langle T^{1/2}u,T^{1/2}v \rangle_{V_0}$ so obviously yes.  $\ \ (v_n)$ orthogonal in $V \implies$ $(T^{1/2} v_n)$ orthogonal in $V_0$. and that it is an orthonormal basis is obvious

Comment: @user1952009 Your equation is wrong. It's only valid for $u,v\in\ker (T^{1/2})^\perp$.

Comment: if $T$ is not inversible then you should not write $T^{-1/2}$ and restate everything clearly. and no in general it is not true that $(P v_n)$ is orthogonal when $P$ is an orthogonal projection (which is what your $T^{-1/2} T^{1/2}$ is)  and $(v_n)$ is orthogonal, simply try with $P v = \langle v, v_1+v_2 \rangle \frac{v_1+v_2}{2}$

Comment: @user1952009 1. I've defined the symbol $T^{-1}$ in the question and it's quite common that $T^{-1}$ denotes the pseudo inverse if $T$ is not injective. 2. Even when $(Pv_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ doesn't need to be orthogonal, when $P$ is an orthogonal projection, that's not a counter-example. Unless you can prove that each orthogonal projection is of the form $T^{-1/2}T^{1/2}$.

Comment: it is obvious that it is a counter-example when $(v_n)$ is abitrary, just try it. if $(v_n)$ is as you wrote the orthonormal basis of eigenvectors, then some $v_n$ are sent to $0$, but the others stay as is, and $(T^{-1/2}T^{1/2}v_n)$ is an orthonormal sequence  (and an orthonormal basis of $Im(T) = Im(T^{-1/2}T^{1/2})$) with some zero vectors inserted

Comment: @user1952009 1. So, you say that $(T^{1/2}v_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ (with the special $v_n$) is an orthonormal basis of $V_0$, right? 2. How do you prove that $(T^{-1/2}T^{1/2}v_n)_{n\in N}$ with $N:=\left\{n\in\mathbb N:\mu_n>0\right\}$ is an orthonormal sequence wrt $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V$?

Comment: I say that $(T^{-1/2} T^{1/2} v_n)$ is in $V$ an orthonormal sequence  with some $0$ vectors inserted, and an orthonormal basis of $Im(T)$ with some $0$ vectors inserted, so that obviously $(T^{1/2}v)$ it is an orthonormal basis of $V_0$ with some $0$ vectors inserted

Comment: @user1952009 Just want to be sure. What about my second question?

Comment: I see no non-obvious question here, except the one about $(P v_n)$ when $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't think that it's obvious that $(T^{-1/2}T^{1/2}v_n)_{n\in N}$ is an orthonormal sequence wrt $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_V$. Unless $v_n\in\ker(T^{1/2})^\perp$. But that's again not obvious to me. If it's obvious to you, I would be very thankful, if you could tell me how we see that.

Comment: because $T^{1/2} v_n = \mu_n v_n$ so that $T^{-1/2} T^{1/2} v_n = 1_{\mu_n\ne 0}v_n$

Comment: @user1952009 Do you mean $T^{1/2}v_n=\sqrt{\mu_n}v_n$ instead of $T^{1/2}v_n=\mu_nv_n$? And what is $1_{\mu_n\ne 0}$? The indicator function? Since $T^{-1/2}$ is not the actual inverse, you cannot simply conclude that $T^{-1/2} T^{1/2} v_n=v_n$ unless $v_n\in\ker(T^{1/2})^\perp$. However, we can show $v_n\in\ker(T^{1/2})^\perp$, so it's fine, but it's not obvious.